# Left join/foreign key question for mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, mysql-error-1064

I have tables queue and requests. queue's reqID is a foreign key to requests' reqID.
both tables have vanID

I am trying to get all the stuff in queue, as well as all the information for each request that queue references. This is my query.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT queue.*, requests.* 
                      FROM queue 
                     WHERE queue.vanID = '$vanID' 
                 LEFT JOIN requests ON queue.reqID = requests.reqID 
                  ORDER BY rank ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

This the error I'm getting.

> 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN requests ON queue.reqID = requests.reqID ORDER by rank ASC' at line 1

I can't seem to figure it out, any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT queue.*, requests.* FROM queue LEFT JOIN requests ON queue.reqID = requests.reqID WHERE queue.vanID = '$vanID' ORDER by rank ASC") or die(mysql_error());
```

You were close. The `WHERE` clause should go after the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

The joins are part of the `from` section of a query, and, as such, must come before the `where` section :

```
SELECT queue.*, requests.* 
FROM queue 
    LEFT JOIN requests ON queue.reqID = requests.reqID 
WHERE queue.vanID = '$vanID' 
ORDER by rank ASC
```